# Getting a list of objects of 2 different lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of action type objects. Each object has a list of departments.

I have a user and a user object has n number of deparments.

I would like to get a list of user actions that the user can take. Here is what I came up with:

```
List<Item> userActions = new List<Item>();
    foreach (var actionType in actionTypelist)
    {
        foreach (var dept in actionType.availableDepts)
        {
            if (data.currentUser.secondaryServDepts.Where(x => x.Id == dept.servDeptId).Count() > 0)
            {
                userActions.Add(actionType);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can you please suggest a better way to get a quicker result? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible optimisation instead of:

```
     if (data.currentUser.secondaryServDepts.Where(x => x.Id == dept.servDeptId).Count() > 0)
     {
         userActions.Add(actionType);
     }
```

Use:

```
     if (data.currentUser.secondaryServDepts.Any(x => x.Id == dept.servDeptId))
     {
         userActions.Add(actionType);
     }
```

Count will enumerate the entire collection while Any will stop at the first match (since all you need is at least one item)

Comment: Thanks, I like that idea!!